# setState doesn't achieve a state change in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to change the page number with setCurrentPage(page) but as I click the button, the state doesn't change at all.  Tried different approaches but nothing worked.

I tried changing the number in useState(1) manually and verified the page changes.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import '../css/page.css';
import '../css/sermons.css';
import SermonModal from "./SermonModal";
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Pagenation from "./Pagenation";

export default function GetAllSermon() {

    const [sermon, setSermon] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [currentPosts, setCurrentPosts] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(3);

    const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/sermons`)
            .then((response) => {
                setCurrentPosts(response.data.sermons.toReversed().slice(firstPostIndex, lastPostIndex));
                setSermon(response.data.sermons.toReversed());
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

    const pages = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(sermon.length / postsPerPage); i++) {
        pages.push(i);
    }

    if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
        <>
            {currentPosts.map((sermon) => (
                <div className="component_sermon_section" key={sermon._id}>
                    <div className="sermon_snap">
                        <a href='#'><img src={sermon.snap} className='sermon_snap' /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sermon_info" >
                        <h3>
                            <SermonModal sermon={sermon} />
                        </h3>
                        <p className='date_time'>
                            {sermon.date.split('T')[0]} @ {sermon.session === 'First' ? '8:00 AM 
                                           1부' : null ||
                                sermon.session === 'Second' ? '09:30 AM 2부' : null ||
                                    sermon.session === 'Third' ? '11:00 AM 3부' : null} -
                                                        {sermon.preacher} 목사
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>))}
            {
                pages.map((page, index) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <button key={index} onClick={() => setCurrentPage(page)}>{page}
                            </button>
                        </>
                    );
                })
            }
        </>
    );
};;
```

Tried setCurrentPage to different page number but didn't work.  Expect it to change the state of currentPage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React update useState() when variable value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840760/react-update-usestate-when-variable-value-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating firstPostIndex and lastPostIndex once, when the component is created, but you actually want them recalculated every time the state changes, so you need to calculate them inside the useEffect.

Put

```
const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage;
```

inside the use effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage;

    axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/sermons`)
            .then((response) => {
                setCurrentPosts(response.data.sermons.toReversed().slice(firstPostIndex, lastPostIndex));
                setSermon(response.data.sermons.toReversed());
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
}, []);
```

Comment: The issue has been fixed! thank you so much!

Comment: On top of the code, please explain what he problem was and how your code solves it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    useEffect(() => {

const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage

            axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/sermons`)
                .then((response) => {
setCurrentPosts(response.data.sermons.toReversed().slice(firstPostIndex, lastPostIndex));
                setSermon(response.data.sermons.toReversed());
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [currentPage]);
```

Most likely curretPage is being updated, but the situation does not change because useEffect is not updated. Try useEffect this way. If not, check whether the page variable is number. Please report the result.

Comment: This is likely not going to work unless the initialisation of firstPostIndex and lastPostIndex are moved inside this useEffect

Comment: I fixed it code

Comment: The issue has been fixed! thank you so much!